# Mercurial notifications when non-whitelisted user commits

Tags: email, mercurial, notifications, bamboo

recently we've had problems where members of another team will commit code to my team's project (this is normal and expected)  but it will break our build or cause tests to fail. We'd love to be able to get an email when those not on our team push changes so that we can make sure they were properly code reviewdc. We're using bamboo for a build tool and mercurial for version control. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably make a 1 line change to the [Notify Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NotifyExtension) that ships with Mercurial to do this.

Comment: I've looked into the Notify Extension, but i need the ability to only email when a user not in a particular group commits/pushes. Do you know if there's a way to add that extra check to the notify config? It looks like you can only configure it to email based on what hg event just happend...

Comment: You can't do it in the config but you could add a single line of code like `if committer in ['me', 'you', 'jim']: return` to do it.  Python is very approachable.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm just not sure how to tie the Python code to the notify extension? Would i be editing the actual extension itself? Or adding a hook?

Comment: The fastest way is to edit the actual extension.  Here it is: http://selenic.com/hg/file/tip/hgext/notify.py  .  You could probably just add something like `if not author in ['me', 'you', 'him']: return` before line 408.